# How to use HTTPS for LiveServerTestCase and StaticLiveServerTestCase?

Tags: django, https, stripe-payments, django-testing

Both `django.test.LiveServerTestCase` and `django.contrib.staticfiles.testing.StaticLiveServerTestCase` use HTTP connections only.

I am currently writing integration/functional tests for a web app where people make payments using Stripe. To display the credit card form that comes from Stripe requires the use of HTTPS on the page, otherwise the credit card form will refuse to load. As such, I need something like `StaticLiveServerTestCase` that uses HTTPS connections so that the credit card form can load and be tested.

What are the available solutions to the problem? Is running an external server (e.g. gunicorn, uwsgi) serving the django project over HTTPS the only viable option?

Of interest:

- https://github.com/django/django/pull/5207 - Rejected proposal for `LiveHTTPSServerTestCase`.

Comment: https://github.com/pbrooks/django-secureliveservertestcase

Comment: Note: As long as you are using the development version of the Stripe API key, here's no need for HTTPS. Stripe will work without HTTPS during development. There's no need to use a HTTPS version of `django.test.LiveServerTestCase` to test Stripe.